# Azure | ADF | How to use a String variable to lookup a Key in an Object type Parameter and retrieve its Value

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory. I'm trying to use a String variable to lookup a Key in a JSON array and retrieve its Value. I can't seem to figure out how to do this in ADF.

Details:

I have defined a Pipeline Parameter named "obj", type "Object" and content: 
`{"values":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}`

[Parameter definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGa5Y.png)

I need to use this pipeline to find a value named "key1" and return it as "value1"; "key2" and return it as "value2"... and so on. I'm planning to use my "obj" as a dictionary, to accomplish this.

Technically speaking, If i want to find the value for key2, I can use the code below, and it will be returned "value2":

```
@pipeline().parameters.obj.values.key2
```

What i can't figure out is how to do it using a variable (instead of hardcoded "key2").

To clear things out: I have a for-loop and, inside it, i have just a copy activity: [for-each contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oVxy.png)
The purpose of the copy activity is to copy the file named `item().name`, but save it in ADLS as whatever `item().name` translates to, according to "obj"

This is how the for-loop could be built, using Python: [python-for-loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bxa5.png)

In ADF, I tried a lot of things (using concat, replace...), but none worked. The simpliest woult be this:

```
@pipeline().parameters.obj.values.item().name
```

but it throws the following error:

`{"code":"BadRequest","message":"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression 'pipeline().parameters.obj.values.item().name'","target":"pipeline/name_of_the_pipeline/runid/run_id","details":null,"error":null}`

So, can you please give any ideas how to define my expression? 
I feel this must be really obvious, but I'm not getting there..... 
Thanks.

Comment: @item() is how you reference the current iteration. What is the foreach iterating over?

Comment: Yes, it is. The foreach is iterating over the output of a filter activity, that returns some files in a directory. It's output is something like this:

 "Output": { "ItemsCount": 8, "FilteredItemsCount": 2, "Value": [ { "name": "key1", "type": "File" }, { "name": "key2", "type": "File" }]}

So the name of each file (`item().name`) is a key in the obj.

Comment: I read your edit, and I'm not trying to give you a hard time, but that is a very different problem than what you originally posted.

Comment: I'm still not very clear on what you need. "item()" is a function that returns the current iteration object inside a for loop - it will never be a property on your parameter, which is how you are trying to use it. If your "obj" has an array property, you can use an ordinal position to address it, like "@pipeline().parameters.obj.values[1]" if that helps.

Comment: In Python I would do this: 

```obj = {"values":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}

var = 'key2'
print(obj['values'][var])
````
I want to do the same thing, in ADF. I'm trying to accomplish it with
`@pipeline().parameters.obj.values.var`, and it is not working

Comment: OK, I think i finally understand, please verify this simplified version: you want to use a String variable to lookup a Key in a JSON array and retrieve its Value.

Comment: Yes Joel, that is it. Any ideas on how I can accomplish that in ADF?

Comment: I updated my answer below - it gets ugly but is doable!

Answer (score 4):

Hello fellow Pythonista!

The solution in ADF is actually to reference just as you would in Python by enclosing the 'variable' in square brackets.

I created a pipeline with a parameter obj like yours

[image]

and, as a demo, the pipeline has a single *Set Variable* activity that got the value for key2 into a variable.

[image]
[image]

This is documented but you need X-ray vision to spot it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#complex-expression-example).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, this is the output of a Filter activity. The Filter activity's output is an object that contains an array named value, so you need to iterate over the "output.value":
[image]

Inside the ForEach you reference the name of the item using "item().name":
[image]

**EDIT BASED ON MORE INFORMATION:**

The task is to now take the @item().name value and use it as a dynamic property name against a JSON array. This is a bit of a challenge given the limited nature of the Pipeline Expression Language (PEL). Array elements in PEL can only be referenced by their index value, so to do this kind of complex lookup you will need to loop over the array and do some string parsing. Since you are already inside a FOR loop, and nested FOR loops are not supported, you will need to execute another pipeline to handle this process AND the Copy activity. Warning: this gets ugly, but works.

**Child Pipeline**

Define a pipeline with two parameters, one for the values array and one for the item().name:
[image]

When you execute the child pipeline, pass *@pipeline.parameters.obj.values* as "valuesArray" and *@item().name* as "keyValue".

1. You will need several string parsing operations, so create some string variables in the Pipeline:
   [image]
2. In the Child Pipeline, add a ForEach activity. Check the Sequential box and set the Items to the valuesArray parameter:
   [image]
3. Inside the ForEach, start by cleaning up the current item and storing it as a variable to make it a little easier to consume.
   [image]
4. Parse the object key out of the variable [this is where it starts to get a little ugly]:
   [image]
5. Add an IF condition to test the value of the current key to the keyValue parameter:
   [image]
6. Add an activity to the TRUE condition that parses the value into a variable [gets really ugly here]:

[image]

**Meanwhile, back at the Pipeline**

At this point, after the ForEach, you will have a variable (IterationValue) that contains the correct value from your original array:
[image]

Now that you have this value, you can use that variable as a DataSet parameter in the Copy activity.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have so far.
My problem is that, inside the ForEach, I want to use that item().name to evaluate my obj parameter, and `@pipeline().parameters.obj.values.item().name` does not work.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following what you are trying to accomplish.